# There are undeclared identifiers when I run a form that has TEmbeddedWB in it

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I just recently installed bsalsa's Embedded Web Browser for Delphi 2009 which I downloaded [HERE](http://www.bsalsa.com/downloads.html) and I followed the step by step instructions for it's installation [HERE](http://www.bsalsa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=904). But then after I added a TEmbeddedWB on my form,I got the following errors:

```
Build
[Pascal Error] EWBAcc.pas(319): E2003 Undeclared identifier: SID_IUniformResourceLocatorA'
[Pascal Error] EWBAcc.pas(327): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'SID_IUniformResourceLocatorW'
[Pascal Error] EWBAcc.pas(555): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'urldll'
[Pascal Error] EWBAcc.pas(586): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Shell32'
[Pascal Error] EWBAcc.pas(597): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'HHCtrl'
[Pascal Error] EWBAcc.pas(649): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Free_Index'
[Pascal Error] EWBAcc.pas(666): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'SHLockShared_Index'
[Pascal Error] EWBAcc.pas(683): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'SHUnLockShared_Index'
[Pascal Error] EWBAcc.pas(700): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'SHFreeShared_Index'
[Pascal Error] EWBAcc.pas(709): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'UrlMonLib'
[Pascal Fatal Error] EwbCore.pas(48): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'EWBAcc.pas'
```

As I've read through various forums that pertain to the same problem as mine,they always mention about adding the Source path of the Embedded Web Browser Package on the Library Path to fix this problem. I've already checked and I am certain that I do have the said path on my Library Path already. Any suggestions? Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The undeclared identifiers cited in your question are declared in the IEConst unit, which comes with EmbeddedWB. The compiler found that unit, or else it would have complained about a missing unit. But it didn't find *IEConst.pas*, or else it would have seen those identifiers. Make sure that if you're recompiling *EwbAcc.pas*, then you don't have any stray version of *IEConst.dcu* somewhere else on your system, perhaps from an older EmbeddedWB version, or from a library path that's configured for unrelated projects.

Those EmbeddedWB source files and *EwbCore.pas* are all distributed in the same directory, and that's where they should remain. If you've copied some of the files into your own project directory, remove them and use the original copies instead, or else make a *complete* copy of the library's source directory.

Comment: Thank you so much. It turns out there's another IEConst.pas that my program is currently using. It is from another component though. I just changed its file name and it works fine now. :)

Comment: Are you sure they're not just two different versions of the same file?

Comment: Yes.They are two completely different files as I have seen the difference of their content all in all. thanks.